# U-SQL - Process Last "n" days files

Tags: azure-data-factory, u-sql

**Environment**

- Azure Data Factory/U-SQL

**Scenario**

- I have ADF pipeline which runs on daily basis.And create the Folder and file in following format.Basically the Date wise folder and files are created.
- **"/Samples/Data/TestDB/{filedate:yyyy}.{filedate:MM}.{filedate:dd}/TestDetail.{filedate:yyyy}.{filedate:MM}.{filedate:dd}.csv";**
- In U-SQL I want to process the last 7 days files. I created the U-SQL script by having virtual column to select last 7 days of files.
- I am running these changes on locally.

**Code**

```
 @userLoginData =
        EXTRACT filedate DateTime,
                UserLoginAuditDetailId Guid,
                UserId string              
        FROM    @userLoginDetailPath   
        USING   Extractors.Csv();

  @extractedLoginData = 
        SELECT 
                UserLoginAuditDetailId,
                UserId             
        FROM    @userLoginData
        WHERE   filedate.Date.ToString("d") == @sliceEndTime.AddDays(-7).Date.ToString("d");
```

**Problem**

I am able to run the script successfully, but the when the Job compile then job graph is showing, it is looking for the files which are more than 7 days. Please find below image.Basically it should not be looking for the file 2017.04.20. Right?

[Job Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vagj8.jpg)

Comment: I wonder if the function calls in your WHERE clause are to complex for it to push the predicate back down to the extractor.... A bit like a field that is no longer sargable. Try changing the data type for the virtual field to a string and doing a simple comparison?

Comment: It is still picking the all the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the solution by using the `BETWEEN` clause and comparing the your fileDate virtual column with the specified date something like,

```
DECLARE @ProcessStart DateTime = new DateTime(@sliceEndTime.Year, @sliceEndTime.Month,@sliceEndTime.Day).AddDays(-n); // n is the no of days 
DECLARE @ProcessEnd DateTime = new DateTime(@sliceEndTime.Year, @sliceEndTime.Month,@sliceEndTime.Day); // current day when slice runs
```

and then you can filter the filedate using

```
SELECT * FROM input WHERE    filedate  BETWEEN  @ProcessStart  AND  @ProcessEnd;
```

This will only process the files specified in the range of `@ProcessStart` and `@ProcessEnd`.

Let me know if it solves your issue.